# Monitoring router with Nagios using MRTG

Tags: monitoring, command-line-interface, router, nagios, warning

I'm monitoring router's Bandwidth Usage in Nagios using MRTG. So if I'll not do this command periodically

```
env LANG=C /usr/bin/mrtg /etc/mrtg/mymrtg.cfg
```

I'll will get this warning in Nagios GUI

```
MRTG data has expired (11 minutes old)
```

and the question is: how I can make it automatic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could automate running your `mrtg` command with cron. If your system has a directory named `/etc/cron.d/`, create a new one-line file there with the following contents:

```
*/5 * * * * root LANG=C /usr/bin/mrtg /etc/mrtg/mymrtg.cfg >/dev/null 2>&1
```

This tells cron to run your command every 5 minutes, as the user root, with `LANG=C` in the environment.

If your system does not have a `/etc/cron.d/`, then you'll have to insert the above crontab line in an alternate place, such as the root user's crontab. You can do that by running `crontab -e` as root. In that case, your crontab line should omit the username field (`root`), but will otherwise be the same as before:

```
*/5 * * * * LANG=C /usr/bin/mrtg /etc/mrtg/mymrtg.cfg >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: worked with creating new file. thanx